# QAOA with Qiskit: Is the initial state affected by the noise model?

Tags: qiskit, noise, qaoa

I'm doing a simulation of the QAOA algorithm with noise via the QAOA class of Qiskit 0.19.
Here's (part of) my code:

```
p=1
In_params=np.random.rand(2*p)*np.pi/2
optalg= SPSA(max_trials=1000)

backend = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
model_device= provider.get_backend('ibmq_16_melbourne')
device_prop = model_device.properties()
noisemodel= NoiseModel.from_backend(device_prop)

quantum_instance=QuantumInstance(backend, shots=1024, noise_model=noisemodel)
qaoa = QAOA(qubitOp, optalg, p, initial_point=In_params, callback= mycallback)
qaoa.expectation=PauliExpectation()
result = qaoa.run(quantum_instance)
```

I'm using the default initial state, that is $|+\rangle^{\otimes n}$, constructed automatically by QAOA using Hadamard gates. I'm using a noise model for the execution: is the initial state construction affected by noise also?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Laura! I don't see exactly where you are using specifying the $|+\rangle^{\otimes n}$ state as initial state for QAOA. By default QAOA should use the zero state as initial state. In general, the initial state is broken down to be a circuit so it will also be affected by the noise model.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment (and for editing my question! I saw in the class QAOAVarForm, in the construct_circuit section that there's always an Hagamard gate acting on all qubits before the circuit (eventually) provided by the user to construct the "Initial state" is appended  That is because i think that uniform state is the default state... Am i wrong?

Comment: Ah, yes the `QAOAVarForm` starts with a layer on `H` gates that is correct. But there also is the explicit `initial_state` argument which can be used to start from a custom initial state. I thought this is what you referred to. As the `initial_state` defaults to $|0\rangle^{\otimes n}$, the state is $|+\rangle^{\otimes n}$ after the first layer.
So yes, the noise model affects the construction of that $|+\rangle^{\otimes n}$ state.